# Promise not returning inside loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have controller and model file. I want to return response of promises from model to controller. In response of my model function `conole.log(response)` giving me my result but i am not able to send it to back to controller function.

My controller function is

```
let filters;
 for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
 filters = await ModelFile.getProductOptions(i);
 console.log(filters); // undefined
}
```

My Model Function is

```
    getProductOptions = (product_id) => {
      connection.query(query1,function(err,rows) {
        var response = [];
        //doing something with rows
        Promise.all(rows.map(function(item) {
            var promise = new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
                connection.query(queryItem,function(err,rows) {
                    //doing something
                    result = rows[0].field;
                    //and want to push it to an array
                    resolve(result);
                });
            });
            return promise.then(function(result) {
                console.log(result); //ok
                response.push(result) //ok
            });
        }).then(function () {
            console.log(response); //ok console is showing the response but when return response it gives undefined in controller function
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Remember to `return response` from the final `then` of the model function.

Comment: when i `return response` it give `undefined` in controller

Comment: Like @jensgram said return response in the final .then() even if you already tried that I suggest you update your code

Comment: You have not promisified the outer `connection.query`.

Answer (score -1):

```
    getProductOptions = (product_id) => {
      connection.query(query1,function(err,rows) {
        var response = [];
        //doing something with rows
        Promise.all(rows.map(function(item) {
            var promise = new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
                connection.query(queryItem,function(err,rows) {
                    //doing something
                    result = rows[0].field;
                    //and want to push it to an array
                    resolve(result);
                });
            });
            return promise.then(function(result) {
                console.log(result); //ok
                response.push(result) //ok
            });
        }).then(function () {
            return response;
        });
    });
}
```

And in controller try this :

```
let filters;
 for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
 ModelFile.getResult(i).then(res => {
  console.log(res);
  filters = res;
 });
 console.log(filters);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but showing error `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` here `ModelFile.getResult(i).then(res => {`

Comment: ModelFile.getResult(i) doesn't exist then. That is a mistake on your end, you provided this in your initial snippet.

Comment: You have to replace  ModelFile.getResult(i) with your getProductOptions function

Comment: it was by mistake. I have updated but still not showing.

Comment: In that case the model function is not returning a "promise-like" / "thenable". Make sure to `return connection.query(…)` too.